# Best rigorous book on probability theory for ESL

Tags: machine-learning, probability, references

I know this is similar to many questions asked here before, but I couldn’t find question that addressed what I need.

I started ESL but I’m having a lot of trouble with the probability theory part of it. I have taken a statistics which covered all the basic concepts but it wasn’t very rigorous so I’m having trouble getting through the book.

So, can someone recommend a good comprehensive book on probability theory to go through before tackling ESL?

Comment: I’m assuming “ESL” stands for “Elements of Statistical Learning”. A free and online book that I’ve personally used is https://probabilitycourse.com/

Answer (score 1):

I found "[A First Course in Probability](http://www.seyedkalali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/A-First-Course-in-Probability-8th-ed.-Sheldon-Ross.pdf)" by Ross the most interesting intro to, well, a first course in stats.

Comment: How would this compare to 'Probability and Measure by Billingsley'? I was considering that one too.

Comment: I think that Ross's is more friendly, with real-life examples, while Billingsley's seems to be more mathematically profound. I think that it is up to you, your enthusiasm and background. Reading each of them cover to cover will give you a lot.